# Spring Data Aggregation taking only default id in nested document structure

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data

I am using an aggregation query to get the list of B objects from a nested document structure in MongoDB. The query works fine in the mongo shell and `C._id` is returned but when I do the same with spring data, it returns the default `A._id`.
This is the document structure having a collection of A, nested with B array and C Array respectively

```
    {
      _id: 1,
      B : [{
            _id: 1.1,
            C : [{
                  _id: 1.1.10
                  type: "input"
                }]
           }]
     }
```

This query returns the 'C._id: 1.1.10'
`db.sw_eng.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$B"},{"$unwind":"$B.C"},{"$match":{"B.C.type":"input"}},{$project:{_id:0, Cid:"$B.C._id"}}]);`

But when i do the same using spring data
`Aggregation getOutputPort = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            unwind(B),
            unwind(C),
            match(...),
            match(...),
            match(...),
            match(...),
            project(B.C._id)
                .andExpression("VALUE").as(B.C.value)

        );`

The expected result should be `id:1.1.10` but in all cases, I am getting `id:1`

Comment: I also tried your query on dummy dataset (as per the schema)  and the query works fine. No issues with the query.

Comment: Use `$unwind` to unwind an array. Your sample document from the collection shows there is no array in your document.